# Accessibility scan failing on use of H1 tag

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm using the CynthiaSays.com portal to test my site (martinspoint.org) for accessibility issues, and it keeps reporting that my use of the H1 tag is invalid:

```
Page does not use headers according to specification.
    https://martinspoint.org/
        Line 192, column 13, H1 element
```

Nothing I've read in the standards suggests why this implementation is failing, so I've had to guess at the reason, so far with no luck. This site doesn't have a true text header anywhere on the page, so I've had to hide it off to the left to include one (or else you get an failure that your using H2 tags without an H1 tag). I had also tried putting it around the logo, but it failed with the same message.

Any ideas what the scan is looking for mechanically that is causing the failure? It feels like something structural, like where the H1 tag is in relation to the other tags, but it's all just guesswork at this point.

Comment: I recommend *not* using Cynthia to test. It is a very old tool and has not been updated in sometime. I recommend using [WAVE](http://wave.webaim.org/) instead

Comment: I've been using both because each tends to find different issues (this being an example - WAVE didn't flag it, but it was WAVE's outline view where I finally caught it). I primarily work out of WAVE then check Cynthia to see if she turns up something different. It definitely feels older and clunkier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - there was an H3 tag hidden up in the login header, and the scan wants the H1 tag to be first. It would be nice if the scan would fail on the placement of the H3 tag instead of the H1 tag, but lesson learned.